# Error al instalar una libreria en un entorno virtual

Tags: python, virtualenv

bueno como dice el titulo, estoy tratando de instalar `pip install mysqclient` pero al hacerlo me lanza el siguiente error:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado:
C:ruta_del_proyecto\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\MySQLdb'
```

y al parecer no solo no funciona en ese entorno si no en ningún otro, pero si puedo instalar a nivel global( sin entorno ) por así decirlo, también probé instalando otras librerías y me da el mismo error ¿ alguien sabe a que se debe este error ?

ni siquiera me daja hacer un `pip freeze > requirements.txt`

```
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='cp1252'>
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

uso python 3.10.2 pero no creo que se deba a la versión

### Edit

al parecer creo que un problema de versiones: yo antes usaba python 3.7 y todos mis proyectos usan esa versión de python ya después cambie a python 3.10 pero aun así me funcionaban correctamente los entornos podía crear uno, instalar librerías, crear archivos requirements, etc.

todos mis proyectos yo los tengo guardados en la carpeta documentos/codigos-python el tema es que no puedo usar virtualenv en toda la carpeta documentos, fuera de ella si puedo usar virtualenv es bastante raro lo que esta pasando

Comment: Necesitamos más información para poder darte alguna ayuda. En lugar del comando `pip` emplea mejor `python -m pip`  para asegurar que estás usando el entorno virtual. Por ejemplo, añade un listado de módulos obtenidos con `python -m pip list`.

Comment: @ChemaCortes me devuelve correctamente los módulos instalados